# WebServer + AP not working? WebServer + STA does

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I've been trying to set up an access point combined with a web server using the ESP8266WiFi libraries for Arduino. I am using an ESP8266 Huzzah module with NodeMCU firmware installed (newest master).

Setting up an AP using softAP works fine, I can also assert a PSK to it and choose which channel to use (I've chosen the one with the least traffic, in this case ch 11). The problem is when trying to access the web server from a connected device, it always ends up with a timeout exception. The ESP's IP is in this case 192.168.4.1 and the port is 80.

I've tried connecting the ESP to another AP (Home router) in STA mode and I am successfully able to connect to the ESP through the given IP Address.

**To sum it all up:**

- ESP8266WebServer + WIFI_AP (Station) => Does not work!
- ESP8266WebServer + WIFI_STA (Client) => Works!

This is how I set the web server up, together with AP:

**In Setup:**

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
[...]
ESP8266WebServer server(80);
[...]
Serial.print("Setting soft-AP ... ");
WiFi.disconnect(true);
WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
delay(100);
boolean result = WiFi.softAP("TestAP", "0123456789", 11); // This does of course return true, and the access point shows up on my device

if(result == true)
{
  Serial.println("Access Point Ready");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP()); // Prints 192.168.4.1
}
else
{
  Serial.println("Access Point Failed!");
}
[...]
server.on("/", [](){
  server.send(200, "text/html", webPage);
  delay(1000);
});
[...]
server.begin();
```

**In Loop:**

```
server.handleClient();
```

Has anyone else done this before and had it work? What am I actually doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that I figured it out partly...

All the time, I was using my smartphone to connect to the ESP AP and trying to access the web server. I tried connecting from my computer and by all the stupidness in this world, it works.

Why I can not connect via the phone is a mystery to me, maybe someone can tell me what is going on here...

Comment: What phone are you using? Android phones (Or, at least all my Nexus devices) will prompt once when connecting saying there's no internet access for this network, and asking if you want to stay connected. If you do not confirm that you want to stay connected, you cannot access the ESP.

Comment: OnePlus Two, yes I noticed exactly what you described to be true.

Comment: Pixel 2 also. A very poor design. On connection a small msg "Wi-Fi has no internet access. Tap for options" is shown, and then disappears after a few secs. At this point, it seems that despite the status bar still showing the wifi as connected (with an x to show no internet access), all traffic out this interface is blocked, even traffic destined to the local subnet. The only way to enable it at this stage is reopen the notification and choose stay connected. The wifi status doesn't even have this option and states "connected, no internet". Poor UI. "Stay connected" should be "Connect anyway"

Answer (score 0):

Basically on certain android devices look out for a notification about staying connected as mentioned in the comments.

If you don't accept staying connected your phone will still show as "connected with out internet" and the page will not load, once you have accepted the notification about staying connected then you can load your wemos page.

On an android nvidia based tablet this was not required, but on my motorola smart phone it would not work until i accepted that box.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was disabling the “WiFi assistant” in the settings by disabling the “Select the best network automatically” option